# The logo/image is not appearing while sending an email with smtplib and email.message.EmailMessage

Tags: python, email, smtplib

I'm trying to send an email with an HTML template. Everything is good but the logo/image is not appearing. What is wrong here and what can I do?

here is the python code:-

```
from flask import request, url_for, render_template
from flask_login import current_user
from ifileshifts import EMAIL_ADDRESS, EMAIL_PASSWORD
from ifileshifts.models import Connection
from email.message import EmailMessage
import smtplib

#fun: Send email.
def send_email(subject, to_email, secret, size, emails, file_count, recipient_type):
    sender_msg = EmailMessage()
    sender_msg['Subject'] = subject
    sender_msg['From'] = EMAIL_ADDRESS
    sender_msg['To'] = to_email
    link = url_for('main.download_link_page', secret=secret, _external=True)
    if recipient_type == 'sender':
        sender_msg.add_alternative(render_template('others/send_email.html', domain=request.url_root, emails=emails, link=link,
        file_count=file_count, size=size), subtype='html')
    else:
        connection_id = Connection.query.filter_by(sender=current_user, receiver_email=to_email).first().id
        open_ifileshifts = url_for('dashboard.messenging', id=connection_id, _external=True)
        sender_msg.add_alternative(render_template('others/receive_email.html', domain=request.url_root, sender_email=emails, link=link,
        file_count=file_count, size=size, open_ifileshifts=open_ifileshifts, subject=subject), subtype='html')
    with smtplib.SMTP_SSL('a2plcpnl0820.prod.iad2.secureserver.net', 465) as smtp:
        smtp.login(EMAIL_ADDRESS, EMAIL_PASSWORD)
        smtp.send_message(sender_msg)
```

here is the image div:-

```
<div class="logo-center" align="center" id="emb-email-header">
    <img style="display: block;height: auto;width: 100%;border: 0;max-width: 50px;" src="{{domain}}static/img/logo.png" alt="" width="50">
</div>
```

Comment: Is that a template?  Who is filling in the {{domain}}?  Or did you shroud that for posting?  Remember that most email clients today do not display images from external web sites unless forced to.  It's possible to have an <img> link pull from another MIME section in the email.

Comment: There is no link from any third-party domain. domain=request.url_root. I used "domain" instead of generating a link with "url_for". But the result is the same

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  When you send an email, the mail reader will be interpreting the HTML as if it were a web browser, but there is no "request" object, and there is no base URL.  When it gets to your <img> tag, how do you think it's going to find the image file?  It either has to reference an absolute URL (http://site.abc/xyz.jpg), or it has to reference an attachment to the message (cid:xxxx).